# Extended Formulaiton and Integer Programming

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, boolean-functions, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

An *extended formulation* (EF) of a polytope $P\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is a system of  linear constraints
$Ex + Fy  = g, y\geq 0$

in variables $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{d+r}$ where $E,F$ are real
matrices with $d,r$ columns respectively and $g$ is a column vector
such that $x\in P$ if and only if there exists $y$ such that the equation above holds.

*size of the EF* is the number of linear constraints.

$P_{\mbox{spanning tree}}(G) = conv\{ \chi^{E(T)} \in \mathbb{R}^{E} : T \mbox{ is a spanning tree of }G \}.$

It is known that this polytope has the following formulation.

$x(E[U]) \leq  |U| -1$ for nonempty $U \subseteq  V $,
$x(E) = |V|-1 $,
$x_e > 0 $ for $ e\in E $

It is also known that the optimal solution of the following LP is 0-1 vector and the EF of spanning tree polytope has the size $O(n^{3}),n $is the size of the vertex set.

minmize:$\sum_{e \in E} c_{e}x_{e}  $

subject to:

$x(E[U]) \leq  |U| -1$ for nonempty $U \subseteq  V $,

$x(E) = |V|-1 $,

$x_e > 0 $ for $ e\in E $

## Q1

Combining the above facts, does the folowing statement hold ?

Statement:

There is the foloowing system of $O(n^{3})$  linear constraints

$\sum_{e \in E} 1\cdot x_{e}\geq |V|-1$

$Ex + Fy  = g, y\geq 0$,

and it holds that  $x\in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ satisfies the above  linear constraints $\iff$  $x\in \{0,1  \}^{d}$

## Q2

Is the significance of the notion of EF that the *small size* linear programming relaxation of 0-1 integer programming which solves some combinatorial problems can compute exact integer solution?

## Q3

Recently [Fiorini, Massar, Pokutta, Tiwary and De Wolf][1] proved that any extended formulation of any of the three polytopes described above require an exponential number of innequalities.  [1]: http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0837

Does  this result means that *small size* LP relaxation of 0-1 integer programming which solves the $NP-complete$ problems can $not$ compute exact integer solution   ?

Comment: Q2: yes; there are also generalizations of extended formulations that deal with integrality gaps and approximating solutions

Comment: Q1: No. Typically you represent the *convex hull* of integer feasible points. Any convex combination of two points will satisfy the constraints, but it may not be 0-1.